# Why does LiveData better than MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

In many samples i see that:

```
 class DataViewModel{
         val data:LivaData<Int>
             get() = _data 

         private val _data = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    }
```

But more simply looks like this:

```
 class DataViewModel{
         val data = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    }
```

so, why need this more complicated code construction with 2 fields?

Comment: So dependents of your viewmodel cannot update the value of your mutable live data object.

Comment: @JohnnyWineShirt give me more open answer, why it so important, please

Comment: Not a lot of sense in all these `get()`. User still can cast data to MutableLiveData outside the DataViewModel and do whatever he wants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a practice designed to restrict modification of the value from outside the class.

`LiveData` is read-only.
`MutableLiveData`, as the name implies, allows one to change the value it holds.

If you expose a `MutableLiveData` directly, like in your second example, any code which can access that `data` field could also modify the value it holds.

Exposing the ability to change `data`'s content from outside `DataViewModel`  class could make it harder to debug and reason about where `data`'s content is coming from at any given time.

Answer (score 5):

`MutableLiveData` is essentially a `LiveData` with public access to two methods `setValue()` and `postValue()` for modifying that data.

Therefore, `MutableLiveData` is needed if you plan to modify the values of the LiveData.

However, in programming, it's a common concept to make your variables immutable or restrict the access of those who can modify the data of an object. You wouldn't want to expose the ability to modify the contents of variables within an object if there's no need to do so.

Therefore, for `MutableLiveData`, we normally use a getter to get it's parent form, which is `LiveData`.

By getting only `LiveData`, we can ensure that those who access the `LiveData` object can only read the values stored within with no ability to change them.

In a sense, it's just the concept of why you should use private variables with getters.

Answer (score 1):

`LiveData` is immutable. In LiveData the methods of `setValue()` and `postValue()` are not public and data is just read-only, whereas  `MutableLiveData` is `LiveData` which is mutable and can access to change the data.
In addition when defines `var data = MutableLiveData<Int>()` allowing public access to a variable that it can't consider 'Encapsulation' subject, but in

```
private var count = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val countValue : LiveData<Int>
    get() = count
```

we define a public value of LiveData for sharing purposes so that it is able to get the value of “count” as the value of that live data.